# Taylor polynomials of degree n

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have this math question that states:

> Find the Taylor polynomials of degree $n$ approximating $ln(1+x)$ for $x$ near $0$.

The $n$'s are 5, 7, and 9.

$f^{(5)}(0)=24$; I got the derivative to be $\frac{24}{(x+1)^5}$

$f^{(7)}(0)=720$; I got the derivative to be $\frac{720}{(x+1)^7}$

$f^{(9)}(0)=40320$; I got the derivative to be $\frac{40320}{(x+1)^9}$

Comment: And ? What is your question ? You are close to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Taylor polynomial is a polynomial.  Anything with $(x+1)^n$ in the denominator is not.  The Taylor polynomial you are looking for is $f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac 1{2!}x^2f''(0)+\dots \frac 1{n!}x^nf^{(n)}(0)$  The three parts ask you to go out to $x^5, x^7,$ and $x^9$ respectively.

Comment: So, would $f^{(5)}(0) = \frac{24}{5!}$?

Comment: No, you were correct that $f^{(5)}(0)=24$ and the other two.  You actually need all the derivatives of $f$ up to the ninth.  You then need to incorporate them into the polynomial I showed.  I corrected a couple typos leaving out powers of $x$

Comment: So for order 5 would it be: $0+x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{2x^3}{3!}-\frac{6x^4}{4!}+\frac{24x^5}{5!}$?

Comment: That is correct.  You can simplify the fractions a bit.